# Calculate elapsed time in a linq query

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, ef-core-2.0

Using System.Linq in a .Net Core application I'm to trying place the date difference between AssignedDate and DateTime.Now into ElapsedTime.

```
var query = from r in _context.Request
    join st in _context.ServiceType on r.ServiceTypeId equals st.ServiceTypeId
    join u in _context.Users on r.AssignedUserId equals u.UserId into ju
    from u in ju.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new RequestDto
            {
                RequestId = r.RequestId,
                UserId = r.UserId,
                //..
                AssignedUserId = r.AssignedUserId.Value,
                AssignedUser = u.Name,
                ElapsedTime = DateDiff(r.AssignedDate, DateTime.Now)
    };
```

The DateDiff is not a valid function.  How would I replace that?

EDIT: Using MicrosoftEntityFrameworkCore 2.0.  Trying EntityFunction is not valid.

Edit again: I could use this on the view side with razor with something like:

```
@if (item.AssignedDate != null){@DateTime.Compare(item.AssignedDate.Value, DateTime.Now)}
```

But that doesn't work??

Comment: Looks like you are using EF Core. Please update the tags and specify the EF Core version.

Comment: `DateTime - DateTime = TimeSpan`...

Comment: Should the diff be in hours, days,....?

Comment: EntityFrameworkCore 2.0   |   the difference should show in Minutes:Seconds

Comment: I personally don't think the "Core" products are ready for most database usage. They have added an `EF.Functions` capability and a `DBFunctions` registration capability, but I don't think it is competitive with the standardized `EntityFunctions`.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately `TimeSpan` and `DateTime` operations support in EF Core is still far form perfect even in the lastest at this time EF Core 2.0.1.

For instance, the natural

```
ElapsedTime = DateTime.Now - r.AssignedDate
```

for SqlServer throws `SqlException` - *"The data types datetime and datetime2 are incompatible in the subtract operator."*.

And attempt to trick it with using variable

```
var baseDate = DateTime.Now;
```

and then

```
ElapsedTime = baseDate - r.AssignedDate
```

leads to another `SqlException` - *"Operand data type datetime2 is invalid for subtract operator."*.

The only way I was able to use w/o error is the `DateTime.Subtract` method:

```
ElapsedTime = DateTime.Now.Subtract(r.AssignedDate)
```

but keep in mind that this leads to [client evaluation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/client-eval).

Comment: Oh, I didn't realise EF Core did client-eval instead of throwing exceptions. I can see a lot of people having perf problems because of this...

Comment: @DavidG Indeed. There is a way to disable it, but then with the current state of SQL translation the EF Core would be practically unusable.

Comment: Starting to think I should switch to Dapper for some donet core Ubuntu dev about to start... :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can change the type of `ElapsedTime`, how about:

```
...
ElapsedTime = (DateTime.Now - r.AssignedDate).Ticks
```

`ElapsedTime` will have to be of type `long` which will hold the difference as [`ticks`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.ticks(v=vs.110).aspx), when you read it back, you can use `TimeSpan.FromTicks(ticksValue)`, then you can choose what members you want (hours, minutes, seconds, fractions, etc...)

Comment: `TimeSpan` is a `.net` type, I don't see why it wouldn't, but I have not tested it with EF.

Comment: It's not a SQL type though, that's the problem. If it doesn't work with EF then this will throw an exception.

Comment: ElapsedTime as a TimeSpan with the expression you offered produces the error, 'Unable to cast object of type 'Sytem.DateTime' to type 'System.TimeSpan'.

Comment: @P-Finny, I've just updated my answer, give it another try.

Comment: @DavidG This theoretically should work in EF Core, but currently it doesn't and throws exceptions as you guessed.

Comment: @IvanStoev So the API isn't there yet?

Comment: @DavidG It actually translates to (some) SQL, but throws at database side - `SqlException`: *"The data types datetime and datetime2 are incompatible in the subtract operator."* :(

Comment: @IvanStoev, sorry, I have no EF handy (no need ATM, and don't want to install just to test this code), but what if the `(a-b).Ticks` is moved to a separate function that returns `long`? In the worst case, I'd see if there is a way to pass both `DateTime` objects to a stored procedure. Or if there is a way to make `TimeSpan` object compatible with EF, a concept similar to serialisation (but completely different in implementation :P).

Comment: @nurchi With EF (Core) everything is different, sometimes work, sometimes not. So the only way to make sure something work is to know the exact version (including the minor) and test :(

Comment: As the last resort, try storing both `DateTime` objects and dealing with the difference when reading the data back...

I'm out of ideas :)